How can I set VLAN settings to persist across boots?
I originally asked this question on the Unix & Linux board, but I guess it's more appropriate to ask it here.
I have an Ubuntu Server 23.10 which is located on VLAN 2 (IP: 192.168.2.100) and I have created another VLAN (192.168.5.xxx) on my switch where I plan to announce some services.
Reading Ubuntu's official wiki on VLAN and following the steps in 'Configuration' makes the services announced from Server-VLAN to Services-VLAN work perfectly. However, I do not know how to make the changes from the 'Making it permanent' chapter permanent, since the wiki is outdated and making changes to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/90-installer-network.cfg and running sudo netplan apply changes the server's IP from 192.168.2.100 to 192.168.5.10, which is not what I want.
The ranges on the Services-VLAN go from 192.168.5.6 to 192.168.5.254, with the default gateway being 192.168.5.1.
# /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist acress an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file:
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2

Applying the config below changes the server's IP from 192.168.2.100 to 192.168.5.10 and is thus unwanted outcome.
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/90-installer-network.cfg

# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2

# My changes (found from various sources on the internet)
  vlans:
    enp3s0.5:
      link: enp3s0
      id: 5
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [ 192.168.5.10/24 ]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.5.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [ 192.168.5.1 ]

Below are the commands passed based on the wiki (which work):
sudo ip link add link enp3s0 name enp3s0.5 type vlan id 5
sudo ip addr add 192.168.5.10/24 dev enp3s0.5
sudo ip link set up enp3s0.5

Any help is greatly appreciated!

can you post output of ip a
